# "ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages"-404 Not Found

Tags: php, ubuntu

I have to update my VPS server today in vain but there are these 404 errors in it. How can I get rid of them?

Because otherwise I don't get a SinusBot installed

```
Err:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main all Packages
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main Translation-en_US
Ign:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal/main Translation-en
Ign:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu focal/main all Pack                                                                                                                               ages
Err:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Pa                                                                                                                               ckages
  404  Not Found
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu focal/main Translat                                                                                                                               ion-en_US
Ign:19 http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu focal/main Translat                                                                                                                               ion-en
Reading package lists... Done
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu focal Release' doe                                                                                                                               s not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potential                                                                                                                               ly dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta                                                                                                                               ils.
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu focal R                                                                                                                               elease' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potential                                                                                                                               ly dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration deta                                                                                                                               ils.
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu/dists/focal/main/b                                                                                                                               inary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/texlive-backports/ppa/ubuntu/dists/f                                                                                                                               ocal/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used                                                                                                                                instead.
```

Answer (score 0):

PPA ondrey PHP and texlive don't support the focal dist (yet).

Try changing the dist from focal to eoan in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ondrej-ubuntu-php-focal.list (or something like that).

Same for texlive-backports but try changing that from focal to precise.